# How to configure Workflow Manager 1.0 for FBA User

Tags: 2013, workflow-manager

I want to configure Workflow Manager 1.0 for FBA user in SharePoint 2013. Please let tell me how to configure it. I tried to configured it, and also user are shown in user profile service. But when I try to start workflow with FBA it gives "Access Denied Error".

Comment: I also have same problem. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: Any Solution so far? am also in a dilemma on this.

Comment: No, this issue is still pending

Comment: Can you add more detail? Have you already successfully paired Workflow Manager with SharePoint? What kind of WF is it?

Comment: I successfully paired Workflow Manager with SharePoint and it working fine for windows user as expected.But user logged as FBA user, workflow get terminated. ULS shows error user not found.

Comment: Are you sure that the FBA user starting the workflow has a SharePoint user profile?

Answer (score 1):

There is no special configuration to be done.  When you configure FBA you are actually configuring claims authentication - and that claim is what is getting passed.

If you have not already - you also need to configure the user profile service.  The user running the workflow needs to have a profile created in the user profile service.  Also ensure you have deployed and there are no issues with the App Management service as well as Secure Token Service.

Comment: I tried this already, but then still getting error

Comment: Have you tried granting [additional permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383(v=office.15).aspx) to the Workflow app on the site where it errors?

Get the ID from the Application Permissions list under the site administration and use the _layouts/15/appinv.aspx to add additional permissions to the user. I usually add site collection full control and many issues go away - granted, more specific permissions might work better security wise.